The paton code with the g4f library returns a 404 error
my code gives error:
from g4f.client import Client

client = Client()
response = client.images.generate(
  model="gemini",
  prompt="a white siamese cat"

  
)
image_url = response.data[0].url

full error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\USER\Desktop\Papo4ki\programir\PYTHON\g4f\main.py", line 4, in <module>
    response = client.images.generate(
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\g4f\client.py", line 168, in generate
    for chunk in response:
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\g4f\Provider\base_provider.py", line 205, in create_completion
    yield loop.run_until_complete(await_callback(gen.__anext__))
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 653, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\g4f\Provider\base_provider.py", line 201, in await_callback   
    return await callback()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\g4f\Provider\needs_auth\Gemini.py", line 73, in create_async_generator
    driver = get_browser(proxy=proxy)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\g4f\webdriver.py", line 64, in get_browser
    return Chrome(
           ^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\undetected_chromedriver\__init__.py", line 258, in __init__
    self.patcher.auto()
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\undetected_chromedriver\patcher.py", line 178, in auto
    self.unzip_package(self.fetch_package())
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\undetected_chromedriver\patcher.py", line 287, in fetch_package
    return urlretrieve(download_url)[0]
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\urllib\request.py", line 241, in urlretrieve
    with contextlib.closing(urlopen(url, data)) as fp:
                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\urllib\request.py", line 216, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\urllib\request.py", line 525, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\urllib\request.py", line 634, in http_response
    response = self.parent.error(
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\urllib\request.py", line 563, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\urllib\request.py", line 496, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\urllib\request.py", line 643, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found

Help me please, i don't know with correct this mistake.
A little earlier, I also encountered this error, but it somehow resolved itself when I The Internet is good then i restarted the code, the program for changing the IP is enabled, because g4f does not work in Russia
